# wordpress multisite not working on Localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've installed wordpress in multisite mode on my localhost. I am using WAMP server on windows 10.

The parent site works well and can be accessed. However when I try to go to the sub sites It says the URL was not found on the server. Both for the sites as well as their backends.

I have followed the network setup instructions as specified by wordpress.

I think it's an issue with mod_rewrite, how ever in my httpd.conf when I uncomment

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I get an internal server error

My htaccess file is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase sandbox/mainsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Another curious thing is that when I change the permalinks in wordpress to custom structure and hit save, it does not get saved and reverts to the previous setting.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You will need to enable `mod_rewrite`, the contents of your `.htaccess` file area being ignored because of the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` check.

Comment: @doublesharp So I removed <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> from the .htaccess and enabled mod_rewrite and I get an internal server error.

Comment: You can leave the `<IfModule>` since it just checks if the extension is loaded before processing the rules inside it, so you just need to enable `mod_rewrite`. Check your error log to get the specifics, but perhaps you don't have `mod_write`?

Comment: I have enabled mod_rewrite by uncommenting the line #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so . I still get an internal server error when I enable it. Thats whats confusing me.

Comment: [Thu Sep 03 12:17:07.506490 2015] [core:alert] [pid 36540:tid 1096] [client ::1:55389] E:/websites/sandbox/mainsite/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL
This is the error from the log

Comment: Got it working and posted an answer. Error Log helped Thanks @doublesharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Fixed the Issue.
The problem was the Rewrite Base was not reading the correct URL.

Adding a '/' before it worked. So I changed

```
RewriteBase sandbox/mainsite/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /sandbox/mainsite/
```

Comment: If your localhost is installed as a subfolder (most are to run multiple sites), then your htaccess `RewriteBase /<subfolder name>/` should point to that subfolder